# Convert PostgreSQL query to Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I need to convert the following SQL query to Entity Framework

```
SELECT * 
FROM "Employee"
CROSS JOIN json_array_elements("Offers"::json)
WHERE value::TEXT IN('1', '3')
ORDER BY "Id" DESC
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: entity framework core we are using

Answer (score 0):

There's no translation from LINQ to PostgreSQL's particular JSON query syntax.

You can populate collections of entities with [Raw SQL Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql).

If the query results don't match an existing entity, you can declare a [Keyless Entity Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types?tabs=data-annotations) that matches the query results.